# How to add a single element to the end of an xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml:

```
<found>
  <name>Crusader</name>
</found>
```

How can I write a stylesheet which will help add another element to this xml?

I want the result document to be something like:

```
<found>
  <name>Crusader</name>
  <tel>12345</tel>
</found>
```

The following replaces the whole document and I just want to add one element at the end

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
   <tel>12345</tel>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way;

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/found">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <tel>12345</tel>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.